# Label error when running AX 2012 for 1st time after installation

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012

Sometimes I am getting an Label error just after a fresh installation of AX 2012 when it should show screen for prerequisites i.e,compilation etc. Its a complete installation including AOS. I got a temporary solution for that as.. if we open a New workspace from the same screen then everything goes fine.. But my question is why that error is appearing at all.
Here is a ScreenShot...
[image]